# Dealing with competition from inside the lab

Tags: ethics, collaboration

I invited a coworker with shared expertise to collaborate on/coauthor a paper (both postdocs). The result was ultimately much better due to this input. He also had an idea for an alternative approach to 'my problem', and published a second paper with me as coauthor. While this is beneficial in the sense that it increases the quality and volume of both our output, I find the situation highly stressful. I am not aggressively competitive by nature and feel that his behaviour is arrogant and offensive. I understand that once you have published a result, any generalization thereof it is ‘up for grabs’. However, people with access to your unpublished work have an ‘unfair’ head start. Is there an unwritten understanding with respect to crossing the borders between the territory of your coworkers? How can I avoid this type of conflict/coworker in the future? Am I being overly sensitive and need to develop thicker skin/not cut out for this type of business?

Comment: I don't understand. The collaborator did invite you to be co-author on a paper whose idea is his. How this is considered arrogant and offensive. How do you "own" a problem?

Comment: This is why I put the ''-marks on 'my problem'. I realize I do not own the problem. But it is mine in the sense that I formulated it, recognized its importance and wish to solve it. 'His idea' is in some respects but a short leap from mine. He did, for example, not need to do formulate the problem or do any literature review, just 'copy' them from my paper. Yet his work completely encompasses mine since it is a generalization, making my work obsolete.

Comment: The move is aggressive and offensive in the sense that he is moving in on 'my territory'. Suppose that one coworker at any kind of workplace started taking over the work responsibilities of others on his own accord. Clearly, this would not be looked kindly upon and would be an unhealthy situation for the workplace.

Comment: It could be argued that others should be grateful that he is doing their work, but in any kind of career orientated workplace I do not think that would be the case.

Comment: "I am not aggressively competitive by nature"... well, judging by your post, you are aggressively competitive. Might be by nurture, though.

Comment: :) I will try to rephrase the question. Someone tells you about his research problem and its solution. Is your reaction along the lines a) cooperative, something along the lines of 'that is interesting, have you thought about this aspect' or b) competitive in the sense of ' I have/can find a better solution'. How does one collaborate with these two different types of people?

Comment: A person who is 'competitive by nature' may prefer collaborations of the type b) since it drives them to excel. In my case I experience stress that I would like to avoid.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand too. Your co-author is collaborating with you to produce high-quality results. What problem do you have this that?

Comment: I find your dichotomy quite strange. I would characterize “That’s cool; have you thout about X?” as mildly interested but not really cooperative, and “I think have a better solution; let’s write a followup paper” as actively cooperative. When I tell people about my research results, the second reaction is the one I really want.

Comment: Is there perhaps a typo and it should have said "without me as coauthor"?

Comment: We have probably received many questions somehow similar to this one showing that actually many PhD students and postdoc don't have a clear idea or totally misunderstand what science is really about.

Comment: To provide some more background: I first told my coworker about a problem I was working on. He proceeded to find a solution that was perceived to be more general and suggested that I abandon my approach. I wanted to go ahead and publish. This lead to some discord, but we reconciled as I offered him co-authorship on my paper and he reciprocated. He had some good input on my paper, making it stronger. I found some mistakes in his paper and suggested corrections.

Comment: It turned out that his result required an assumption that mine did not. I made that the selling point of my paper. Having learnt of this nice property of my approach, he proceeded to generalise the paper a second time. This will be the third paper. As such, our relationship is productive. However, I am afraid that the next time I approach him with an idea, his MO will be to one-up me once more. I find this aspect of our collaboration stressful and wonder how to deal with such feelings?

Comment: Asdf, ideas are a dime a dozen: the value is in making the idea work. Since you two together seem to make ideas work better than they would if you worked on your own, try to turn this in a long standing collaboration in which no one cares about whose idea is which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Science is a collective endeavour to build and spread knowledge, improving our understanding of nature. Collaborating and building on each other's expertise with proper recognition is a must.

You collaborated with a colleague of yours, and not only did this joint effort  produce a better result, but it also produced a further result, unforeseen at the beginning (and which, for you, came almost for free).

Celebrate the successful moment, hope that all your future collaboration will work out smoothly and productive as this one, and if necessary rethink carefully at your motivation in doing science, to avoid being stressed by something that should be the normality (and that too frequently, alas, is not). That is, be competitive against *yourself* to improve yours and everyone's knowledge and not against someone else.

Comment: Yes, I think something like this should be the right course moving forward. I guess there are many aspects of work in academia that perhaps do not seem natural to everyone on first encounter, but over time one adjusts and become comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

It is rather common for a problem or question to be generalized, that does not mean that the original problem becomes void. Furthermore, the very reason to publish a paper should be to interest others in the topic and not to just increase your paper count. He also included you as a co-author in his paper that, given your formulation, he wrote almost by himself based on your work together, so I'd think that he is more than willing to give you credit for your work.
I would suggest to communicate with the coworker and discuss future work on this field. There are three choices here:

1) You both want to continue to work together on the topic. No problem then, just do it; you only need to decide who is first author, if that is an issue in your discipline.
2) You both want to continue to work on the topic, but not together. That might cause some problems and I would suggest to agree on different aspects for you to work on if possible, otherwise you might happen to publish similar results at around the same time.
3) One of you doesn't want to work on the topic any more. Then the other is free to do as he pleases, of course giving due credit to the other author by citing your joint papers.

Comment: I talked to him. We have chosen option 1). I think the future holds more stressful moments like this one, but hopefully I learn to recover from them faster.